# Rails 3.0.3 resource route no index mapped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to use a very simple resource route for my Buildings Controller.

```
resource :buildings
```

This results in the following mappings

```
buildings POST   /buildings(.:format) {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"create"}
         new_buildings GET    /buildings/new(.:format)          {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"new"}
        edit_buildings GET    /buildings/edit(.:format)         {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"edit"}
                       GET    /buildings(.:format)              {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"show"}
                       PUT    /buildings(.:format)              {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"update"}
                       DELETE /buildings(.:format)              {:controller=>"buildings", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Anyone know why there is no index action mapped for the default /buildings GET request? I'm using rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think you want to use `resources` instead of `resource`. You can read about the difference here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource